# How do I export non-face edges with Blender's Python API?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, export

So I have an exporter, where I export the meshes as faces. But if I try to also export the lines that does not have faces, I get all lines including the ones surrounding faces.

So if I do:

```
Object.data.edges
```

I get all edges, not only the edges that is not part of faces.

So, how do I ask Blender to get me all the lines, except those around faces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a direct method to get the list of free-edges (not comprising faces), but you can find them using this script:

```
import bpy, bmesh

o = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh( o.data )

faceEdges = set( [ e.index for f in bm.faces for e in f.edges ] )
allEdges  = set( range( len( bm.edges ) ) )
freeEdges = allEdges.difference( faceEdges )

print( "Indices of non face edges: ", freeEdges )
```